# How to configure eventNotification on DocuSign PowerForms/Templates

Tags: python, rest, docusignapi

#### Question

I'd like for all the documents created by a single DocuSign Template/PowerForm to be configured with a webhook so that I don't need to [continuously poll every 15 minutes](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/status_and_events.html) to get completed documents. I've done a lot of reading, and want to know if this is even possible in the DocuSign API.

#### Background

I have a self-service waiver document: Users navigate to a URL, fill out their contact information (i.e. define a Recipient role), and expect that their completed waiver is recognized by a linked system.

I have a [DocuSign template](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates) that is being used in a [PowerForm](https://www.docusign.com/features-and-benefits/features/powerforms): Users navigate to the PowerForm's URL, and the PowerForm will let them create a new Envelope from the associated Template.

I'd like for the documents created by this setup to automatically notify an HTTPS endpoint upon completion, via a standard [webhook](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#webhooks).

#### Attempted solutions

The [`Envelopes::create`](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) method (`POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes`) accepts an `eventNotification` parameter that can be used to configure webhooks. The [webhook recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status) covers usage of this endpoint quite nicely. This would solve my problem, if I were creating every Envelope via an API request, but I like the ease of a copy-pastable URL that comes with a PowerForm.

It's not documented, but it appears that [`Envelopes::update`](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/) (`PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}`) may support configuring notifications on an already-created envelope. I could repeatedly [query the most current envelopes](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatus/) for my template, update the notifications on in-progress envelopes and process the completed ones, but that's no better than polling.

I browsed the [REST API](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/), specifically the [Templates](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/) and [PowerForms](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/PowerForms/) categories, but I don't see any obvious way to configure either resource to set `eventNotification` on created envelopes.

Here's a quick code dump of some of the API exploration I've done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests


username = 'user@example.com'
password = 'some-sensitive-password'
integrator_key = 'abcdef01-2345-6789-0abcdef0123456789'


# Authenticate to the DocuSign API, get the base URL for subsequent requests
authenticate_str = (
    "<DocuSignCredentials>"
    "<Username>" + username + "</Username>"
    "<Password>" + password + "</Password>"
    "<IntegratorKey>" + integrator_key + "</IntegratorKey>"
    "</DocuSignCredentials>"
)
headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': authenticate_str,
           'Accept': 'application/json'}
api_base = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/'
resp = requests.get(api_base + 'login_information', headers=headers)
base_url = resp.json()['loginAccounts'][0]['baseUrl']

# Identify all templates in my account
resp = requests.get(base_url + '/templates', headers=headers)
all_templates = resp.json()['envelopeTemplates']

# (Find my template, explore ways I could modify it with PUT, etc.)
template_id = find_desired_template(all_templates)
resp = requests.get(base_url + '/templates/{}'.format(template_id), headers=headers)

# Find just status changed envelopes from some recent date/datetime
resp = requests.get(base_url + '/envelopes',
                    params={'from_date': '2018-01-26'}, headers=headers)

# Configure just a single envelope to have push notifications
envelope_id = resp.json()['envelopes'][0]['envelopeId']

# Configure this _one_ envelope to notify us when completed.
# WARNING: This isn't repeatable: The next auto-created envelope won't work
event_notification = {
    "url": "https://my-own-api.example.com/some/endpoint",
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "useSoapInterface": "false",
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
    "includeDocuments": "true",
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "true",
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
    "includeDocumentFields": "true",
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "true",

    # Only notify on completion
    "envelopeEvents": [
        {"envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"}
    ],
    "recipientEvents": [
        {"recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"},
    ],
}

requests.put(base_url + '/envelopes/{}'.format(envelope_id),
             headers=headers,
             json={'eventNotification': event_notification})
```

#### Constraints

My account is not configured to have [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#docusign-connect), which would allow me to notify the HTTPS endpoint *every* time a document in my account is completed. I'm on a shared account (with other irrelevant Envelopes/Templates being used), so this is not an ideal solution anyway.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. Connect is annoying to use. I'd much rather attach the eventNotification object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For business reasons, Connect webhooks can only associated with all envelopes (or all envelopes from a template/powerform) if the Account-level Connect option is purchased. It is available as an add-on for many account types.

In that case, as you mention, your webhook listener will receive notifications of envelope events that it is not interested in. For those notification messages, respond 200 (received) and then discard the information.